# Pex suggest a solution with Moles's error

Tags: moles, pex

I try to use Pex to explore the following method :

```
public float MultiplyFloat(float a, float j)
{
    if (a * a == 2)
    {
    if (j == 123)
    {
        a = 2;
    }
    }
    else
    a = 3;

    return 3;
}
```

I know that the Z3 is a linear arithmetic solver and floating point is not supported but Pex wizard in Visual Studio 2010 add-on suggest me to "Moles Type" , I use this suggest and Pex Wizard create :

1) the Microsoft.Pex.Framework.moles file

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
  <Assembly Name="Microsoft.Pex.Framework" />
</Moles>
```

2) a prepared class :  __TestabilityHelperPreparation

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Pex.Framework;
using Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Symbols.Moles;
using Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Symbols;

namespace Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Symbols.Preparations
{
    /// <summary>Contains a method to prepare the type __TestabilityHelper</summary>
    public static partial class __TestabilityHelperPreparation
    {
        /// <summary>Prepares the environment (and the moles) before executing any method of the prepared type __TestabilityHelper</summary>
        [PexPreparationMethod(typeof(__TestabilityHelper))]
        public static void Prepare()
        {
            M__TestabilityHelper.BehaveAsCurrent();
            // TODO: use Moles to replace API that call into the environment
        }
    }
}
```

but not compile with the following errors :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\MsBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets(274,5): error MSB3073: uscita dal comando ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bin\sn.exe" /R "o\Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Moles.dll" "m.g.snk"" con codice 9009. [D:\BenchMarkTesterToolLib.Tests02\obj\Debug\Moles\mpf\m.g.csproj]

Moles compilation FAILED - 58,028916314783s

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\Microsoft.Moles.targets(79,5): error MSB3073: uscita dal comando ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @D:\BenchMarkTesterToolLib.Tests02\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args" con codice -1002.
```

So, Do I an error or is Pex to suggest me a wrong solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually with Code Contracts, it is running the wrong version of `sn`.  This has been fixed in the latest version of Code Contracts.  So try updating Code Contracts and try again.

Comment: Ok I installed new version Release 1.4.51019.0 (October 19, 2012)
Now not compile because I haven't the Moles namespace : 
Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Symbols.Moles

Comment: That sounds like your project is missing the pex assemblies in references.